# Add Numbers Until Palindromic

Tags: c#, palindrome

I've been working on a C# console application, and have successfully instituted a palindromic check based on the user inputing an int. I'm now having trouble with the condition involving addition of the user input and the reverse of said input. I want to continue checking for a palindromic number via this addition and then stop execution of the program when one is reached. My program appears to have difficulty saving the state of the reversed number, any help would be much appreciated:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MathPalindromeConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, temp, remainder, reverse = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer \n");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool palindromic = true;
            temp = num;
                while (num > 0)
                {
                    remainder = num % 10;
                    reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
                    num /= 10;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Given a number is = {0}", temp);
                Console.WriteLine("Its reverse is = {0}", reverse);
                while (palindromic)
                {
                    if (temp == reverse)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Number is a palindrome \n");
                        palindromic = false;
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (temp != reverse)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Number is not a palindrome \n");
                        Console.WriteLine(temp += reverse);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: By the time you get to the line `Console.WriteLine(num += reverse);`, `num` is equal to zero. Could that be important?

Comment: Made a few mods. num was one issue. Changed num to temp. Still have some adding reversed number issues though

Comment: What do you expect that adding the reverse number will do? If there is no carry, you will get a palindrome - but if any pair of digits is grater than 9, you will not end up with a palindrome. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: `bool pal = num.ToString() == new string(num.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());`

Comment: Still making attempts. The tricky part is the if(temp != reverse) section. So, if not a palindrome, then I want to add temp and reverse together and preserve that number as temp for the next loop to reapply the check logic.

Answer (score -1):

I was going to say the same thing as L.B.  He put it in a comment, so I'll put it here.  Why not use:

```
bool pal = num.ToString() == new string(num.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
```